# Automatically Extracting the Datetime Format from a Pandas Series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

How can I get the datetime format from a pandas dataframe column? Format Can be anything "%Y-%m-%d", "%Y-%m", "%m-%Y", etc.

Comment: you can transform any object to the date format that you want, you can just use the one you want

Comment: Series can be np.datetime64 type  or object type depending on the person who has given the input. Now I want to know its format.

Comment: @DanCor that's not what I want.

Comment: I datetime in pandas only format is `"%Y-%m-%d"`, so if there are nother formats like "%Y-%m", "%m-%Y" it  is strings repr of datetimes

Comment: @jezrael Suppose format is "%Y-%m",  how can I detect this format without hardcoding as there can be different kinds of format.

Comment: I guess regex, but It is more complicated, if need `%Y-%m"` vs `%Y-%d"` for `2000-05` it is parse `5` for day? or for month? This is really complicated  and problematic, the best is change data in question with [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add expected output

Comment: @jezrael Yes, that's why wanted to get a confirmation from an expert. Thanks